# line caps extend over grid and line axis in tikz pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem but didn't find a solution yet. I am creating a plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz, class=scrreprt, fontsize=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[stretch=10, shrink=10, final]{microtype}
\usepackage[detect-family, detect-weight]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy, intersections, backgrounds}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily\normalsize}}}

\definecolor{dark}{RGB}{215,48,31}              % dunkelrot
\definecolor{yellow}{RGB}{253,204,138}          % gelb
\definecolor{light}{RGB}{254,240,217}           % hellgelb

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                compat = 1.18,
                width = 20cm,
                height = 10cm,
                xmajorgrids,
                ymajorgrids,
                axis y line = left,
                axis x line = bottom,
                x axis line style = {line width = 1pt, line cap = round, -{Triangle[width = 6pt, length = 6pt, round, line width = 1pt]}, shorten >= -0.75cm},
                y axis line style = {line width = 1pt, line cap = round, -{Triangle[width = 6pt, length = 6pt, round, line width = 1pt]}, shorten >= -0.75cm},
                grid style = {line width = 0.2pt, draw = light, opacity = 0.5, line cap = round},
                legend style = {draw = black, line width = 0.5pt, legend cell align = left, at = {(1, 1)}, anchor = north east}
        }}
        \begin{axis}[%
            xmin = 115, xmax = 135,
            ymin = -1.2, ymax = 1,
            xtick = {115, 120, 125, 130, 135},
            ytick = {-1.2, -1, 0, 1},
            xticklabels = {0, 5, 10, 15, 20},
            yticklabels = {\hphantom{$\mathsf{-20}$}, $\mathsf{-1}$, $\mathsf{0}$, $\mathsf{1}$},
            xlabel = {Zeit (in \si{\second)}},
            ylabel = {Blinkerstellung \vphantom{(in \si{\percent)}}},
            rounded corners = 1pt,
            clip = false
            ]
            
            \addplot[draw = black, line width = 2pt, line cap = round] table[col sep = comma] {%
                x       y
                115,0
                119.76,0
            };
            \addlegendentry{keine Blinkerbetätigung}
            
            \addplot[draw = dark, line width = 2pt, line cap = round] table[col sep = comma] {%
                x       y
                119.76,0
                119.760000000000001,1
                123,1
                123.000000000000001,0
            };
            \addlegendentry{Blinker links}
            
            \addplot[draw = black, line width = 2pt, line cap = round] table[col sep = comma] {%
                x       y
                125.400000000000001,0
                135,0
            };

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I am using `clip=false` like in the example the round line caps are extending over the x axis on both sides. I tried to do it without the clip function but then the red line gets cut on the upper side because of the thicker line width that I don't want to change. Another solution I tried is to use `shorten`, but it also extends the grid.

Is it possible to clip only the x axis grid without clipping the red line on the y axis (y = 1)? Or can I extend the y axis so the grid of the y axis is not extending?

Comment: A solution can be remove `line cap = round` at the first (most left) black line.

Comment: I want to keep the round line caps :) But is it possible to keep the round line caps only for one side of a line? That would also be an acceptable solution

Comment: You can not have both. What is acceptable is opinion based. For example, your MWE unnecessary complex and result is not nicer if you will use default settings of `pgfplots`.  Well than try the correct the first table to `x       y
                115.02,0
                119.76,0`

Comment: In the end it is not a good solution in my opinion and it is not answering my question. But you are right, I made the code somewhat shorter and deleted some unnecessary code. It should be less complex now.

Answer (score 1):

That is very opinion based answer ...

Your image I would draw on the following way (which not consider suggestion in my comment):

```
\documentclass[tikz, class=scrreprt, fontsize=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{sansmath}   % <--- new
\usepackage[stretch=10, shrink=10, final]{microtype}
\usepackage[detect-family, detect-weight]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18,
             width = 20cm,
             height = 10cm,
% if yo prefer you can add settings for layers, 
% but for this particular picture are not needed
                }

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds, 
                calc, 
                decorations.pathreplacing, 
                calligraphy, 
                intersections, 
                positioning, 
                shapes}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily}}}

\definecolor{black}{RGB}{0,0,0}                 % schwarz
\definecolor{dark}{RGB}{215,48,31}              % dunkelrot
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{252,141,89}           % orange
\definecolor{yellow}{RGB}{253,204,138}          % gelb
\definecolor{light}{RGB}{254,240,217}           % hellgelb
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}           % weiß


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis line style = {line width = 1pt, line cap = round,
                       -{Triangle[width = 6pt, length = 6pt, round, line width = 1pt]}},
%
    enlarge x limits = {upper,value=0.05},
    enlarge y limits = {upper,value=0.1},
%
    xmin = 115, xmax = 135,
    ymin = -1.2, ymax = 1,
    xtick = {115, 120, ...,135},
    ytick = {-1.2, $-1$, 0, 1},
    xticklabels = {0, 5, ..., 20},
    yticklabels = {,$\mathsf{-1}$ , 0 , 1},
    xlabel = {Zeit (in \si{\second)}},
    ylabel = {Blinkerstellung},
    rounded corners = 1pt,
%
    tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily,
                        /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed,
                            precision = 2,
                            use comma,
                            1000 sep = {}},
    every axis plot post/.append style={line width = 2pt, line cap = round}
                ]

            \addplot[draw = black] table[col sep = comma] {%
                x       y
                115,0
                119.76,0
            };
            \addlegendentry{keine Blinkerbetätigung}

            \addplot[draw = dark] table[col sep = comma] {%
                x       y
                119.76,0
                119.760000000000001,1
                123,1
                123.000000000000001,0
            };
            \addlegendentry{Blinker links}

            \addplot[draw = black] table[col sep = comma] {%
                x       y
                125.400000000000001,0
                135,0
            };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]